# zsh doesn't log not found commands to history

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history

There's a way to setup zsh to not save commands not found to history ?

For example, if by mistake I type:

```
got push
```

instead of

```
git push
```

then `got push` entry is added to history file, how to stop this ?

Comment: @mpy Actually not, the question is for failed commands which includes "not found" but includes also when the application return a status code different than `0`. I only want the "not found" to not be included in history.

Comment: Despite of the possibly ambiguous linked question title, these Q&A do exactly cover this case: Failed command due to _command not found_ are omitted from history, while commands with return code > 0 _are_ stored.

Comment: Yeah now precise looking the title is ambiguous IMO. and sorry my bad, it solves thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Command not found is an error. I don't think zsh differentiate this particular error with other errors, for example "missing parameter" etc.

The post  might be helpful to you: 
[Keep only successful commands in BASH history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41739/keep-only-successful-commands-in-bash-history)

Comment: IMHO, "not found" isn't the same as "missing parameter", since "not found" is when the executable isn't found in PATH while "missing parameter" is when executable is found in path and return status code other than 0. so I think a more specific workaround can be made.